# MotionLayout progress jumps from 0 to 1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-motionlayout

i´m new with MotionLayout and im having trouble to understand where the problem that i have come from. I have 2 recyclerviews in a motionlayout, one horizontal and one vertical. I couldn´t make the animation work when i was scrolling vertically the horizontal recycler, i solved that putting that recycler in a nestedScrollView, but now the progress seems to jump from 0 to 1 directly. Anyone knows whats going on?

FRAGMENT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_lista_principal_scene"
    tools:context=".framework.ui.main.fragments.FragmentListaPrincipal">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearADesaparecer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imagen"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvPromociones"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imagen" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/menuRapido"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/linearADesaparecer">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rGroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbSugerencias"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubunturegular"
                android:padding="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:text="Sugerencias"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbMeriendas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubunturegular"
                android:padding="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:text="Meriendas"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbMinutas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubunturegular"
                android:padding="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:text="Minutas y tablas"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbPostres"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubunturegular"
                android:padding="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:text="Postres"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbCervezas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubunturegular"
                android:padding="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:text="Cervezas"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbTragos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/ubunturegular"
                android:padding="@dimen/common_padding_min"
                android:text="Tragos y vinos"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


        </RadioGroup>


    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvProductos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/menuRapido"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_producto" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/shimmerProductos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/item_producto_load" />

                <include layout="@layout/item_producto_load" />

                <include layout="@layout/item_producto_load" />

                <include layout="@layout/item_producto_load" />

                <include layout="@layout/item_producto_load" />

                <include layout="@layout/item_producto_load" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.facebook.shimmer.ShimmerFrameLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnVerCarrito"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_padding_default"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:text="ver carrito"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

MOTION SCENE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
       <KeyFrameSet>
       </KeyFrameSet>
        <OnSwipe motion:dragDirection="dragDown"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom"
            />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/linearADesaparecer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/menuRapido"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/linearADesaparecer" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/linearADesaparecer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/menuRapido"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/rvProductos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/menuRapido"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

Comment: https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/tree/main/demoProjects/ExamplesRecyclerView
Theses are a collection of demos of common patterns of the use of RecyclerView

Comment: To get help you will need visualization of what you are trying to achieve.
having ```touchAnchorSide="bottom"``` and no touchAnchor does not make sense.

Comment: hello mate, i was just about to quit and i tried your solution and it worked perfectly. I just needed the touchAnchorId. Thank you very much!